# Axios : Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Methods is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight respones

Tags: javascript, firebase, xmlhttprequest, cors, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to send a POST request from  onesignal api

**CODE**

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic NTRjZDY1O....',
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'*',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache'
  },
  data: {
    "app_id": "8e86143e-00.......",
    "contents": {
      "en": "test api"
    },
    "included_segments": [
      "All"
    ]
  }
}).catch(function (error) {
  if (error.response) {
    console.log('error-response-data-'+error.response.data);
    console.log('error-response-status-'+error.response.status);
    console.log('error-response-headers-'+error.response.headers);
  } else if (error.request) {
    console.log('error-request-'+error.request);
  } else {
    console.log('Error', error.message);
  }
});
```

**ERROR OUTPUT**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications
>   Request header field Access-Control-Request-Methods is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKXTF.png)

Would fix it,but it didn't. Does anyone have any information on this error and/or how I can fix it?
**i'm using firebase hosting**

Comment: any solution about this?

Answer (score 2):

**CORS** should be enabled in the **server side** in order to access the API

Comment: i"m using  firebase hosting